# function to get 2d-arrays from stack and heap

Tags: c, arrays, memory, memory-management, malloc

Consider a simple struct, `Foo`, which contains a pointer to some other strucrt, `Baz`. and a two-dimensional array, (stack-allocated):
 `Foo arr[ARR_SIZE][ARR_SIZE];`

Next, consider a function which `malloc`s (in the heap, obviously) a memory for a new 2d-array of `Foo`s. A code snippet:

```
Foo** arr_copy = malloc(sizeof(Foo*) * ARR_SIZE);
for (int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++)
{
    arr_copy[i] = malloc(sizeof(Foo) * ARR_SIZE);
}

for (int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++)
{
        for (int j = 0; j < ARR_SIZE; j++)
        {
            arr_copy[i][j].baz = malloc_baz();
        }
}
```

Now, in my project I have various of functions which need to handle both the original array (stack allocated) and the copy (which is heap-allocated)

Problem is, things got quirky (memory looks corrupted) when I passed the copy to some function which iterate the 2d-array and print some info.

Basically, I know that there should not be a difference between: `void fun(Foo** arr)` to `void fun(Foo arr[ARR_SIZE][ARR_SIZE])` but both ways were problematic.

So my question is, how can a function handle both arrays, stack/heap allocated?

Thanks.

Comment: Functions don't care about the array locations (unless they are allocated by these functions). It's all memory for them.

Comment: make as `Foo (*arr_copy)[ARR_SIZE] = malloc(sizeof(*arr_copy) * ARR_SIZE);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, could you explain the diffrence between the two `malloc`s?

Comment: Different memory image.

Comment: Could you extend your answer please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to do this in c or c++:

```
 int test[][];
```

you will  get this error:

```
error: declaration of 'test' as multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first
```

This is because test is not in fact a double ponter as you'd expect. But the compiler converts it into a single block of data. And this:
    int test[XSIZE][YSIZE];
    int n = test[x][y];

will be converted into something like this:

```
int test[XSIZE*YSIZE];
n = test[YSIZE*x + y];
```

For solving this, i think @BLUEPIXY already put a solution in the comments.
Also, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new).